# How to switch between toggle and removeClass depending on condition in a Jquery chained statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, removeclass

I have the following element handling inside a `tap` event binding.

```
 $el
   .doThis
   .end()
   .find( "a" ).first().removeClass( someClass );
```

I need to include a check for condition `o.direction == "horizontal"` and if the condition is true, I need to `toggle` instead of `remove`

However I can't get it to work. Trying like this:

```
 $el
   .doThis
   .end()
   .find( "a" ).first().toggleClass( someClass , ( o.direction == "horizontal" ? !isCollapse : event ) );
```

Toggles the class correctly if `o.direction == "horizontal"`, but if it's not, I cannot `remove` instead of `toggle`.

**Question:**
Is there a way to check for a condition and perform a `toggle` if condition is met and a `removeClass` if not in a chained jquery statement?

Comment: the second parameter to toggleClass is boolean. what is `event` in your code? passing `false` as the second param will remove the class.

Comment: Sheesh. Just stop trying to one-line everything and use an `if-else` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$el
   .doThis
   .end()
   .find( "a" ).first()[o.direction == 'horizontal' ? 'toggleClass':'removeClass']( someClass )
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve issues where I am not sure what the element state is during runtime and it is very hard to have a variable with that state around I usually use data-attributes and then have the code manage them.

```
<div data-direction="horizontal">
```

and then

```
if(element.getAttribute("data-direction") == "horizontal")
{
 //TODO: remove or toggle
}
```

Manage the state with

```
element.setAttribute("data-direction","state");
```

Comment: hm. keeping this in mind as well. I already was using data-type="horizontal", which I then set in my options as `o.direction = $el.jqmData("type")`

Answer (score 1):

The `event` object shouldn't be used in the `else` condition. You should use `false` instead:

```
.toggleClass( someClass , ( o.direction == "horizontal" ? !isCollapse : false ) )
```

This means that if `o.direction == "horizontal"`, the css class would be toggled depending on `isCollapse` value. Otherwise, the css class will be removed.

Comment: cool. I did not know about `false`. thx